# Virtual Families: the "Margaret Mystery?"

Tags: virtual-families-2

I am on my 4th generation in Virtual Families 2 but something strange is happening. I keep getting notifications every few hours about something about a person named "Margaret". It said that I found a funeral book that showed a funeral at the house for a person named "Margaret", and yesterday I got an in-game email to Margaret and Bob. I have no Margaret or Bob in my family tree, so is this a glitch or a mystery to make the game more interesting? I don't think its a glitch but I want to know if it is like a mystery or something.

Here is a picture of my family tree:

[image: Family tree![][1]]

All my couples are: Fabiana & Stephory,   Friana & Bug,   Lucie & Atom,    Wifi & 
Logone

See? No Margaret or Bob.

Answer (score 2):

Bill and Margeret is the one who first owned the house.
I have quite a bit pieced together: There was a guy named Bill. He went and bought empty land to build a house on (deed of purchase.) Then, once it was finished, he had a party to celebrate. One of his friends brought their sister, Margaret, to the party, and Bill and Margaret fell in love. (House warming) However, once married, Bill went on a trip and while he was gone, Margaret hired some workers to extend the house, which Bill did not appreciate because he felt that the house was too big already. (The angry note) but Margaret wrote back explaining that once they had children, they would need the space. Bill saw her point and wrote back, agreeing with her completely and letting her continue extending the house. (Sad note) later, Margaret had plans for each room but sadly construction of the house was never completed because Bill died in a tragic accident (funeral book) and Margaret held his funeral in the blue room, then abandoned the house out of grief, never to return. Hope this answers your questions!

Answer (score 1):

Maragarate and bill are the people who built the house. They could not have children so when they died, there was no one to inherit the house. It was left empty, so the little people you choose can live in the house.